# Configuring Varnish as a permanent persistant storage caching

Tags: centos, cache, varnish

Currently we have a static storage for our web app, and since the data structure has been really flat; we are in the process of setting up a varnish on the new storage set-up so that it fetches the data from the old storage and while serving it saves the file persistently onto its own disks in a structured way(SSD+SAS). now the environment are standard CentOS 7 and epel installation of Varnish V4.1.
I know that per the docs [here](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/storage-backends.html) varnish supports persistent storage(experimental) but could not find any reliable source of Internet howto set it up. The one liner I use for /etc/varnish/varnish.params is:

```
VARNISH_STORAGE="persistent,/var/varnish,2000M"
```

But can not get the service run. I did check all the possible logs and permission but could not fine any hint ....can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Just learnt from the Varnish book from varnish software that the choice is deprecated:
 P74:

> 5.2 Storage Backends • The storage option -s defines the size of your cache and where it is stored • Use varnishd -s followed by one of the
>   following methods to allocate space for the cache: • malloc • file •
>   persistent (deprecated) • mse Varnish Massive Storage Engine (MSE) in
>   Varnish Plus only